# PHP - Read cell on PHPExcel as it is on xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have some cell on excel file with General format.
The value of this cell is

```
1,99
10,88
```

Using phpexcel, When I read the cell i got:

```
1.99
10.88
```

How can I get the original value 1,99 ?

I did try

```
$sheet->getCell("C2")->getValue();
$sheet->getCell("C2")->getFormattedValue()
```

But both return the

```
1.99
10.88
```

Comment: you will have to use a string format for the cell, not a number

Comment: it not me. The user upload their excel file and for default the format is General. When they type 1,9 the General format keep it like that on Excel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPExcel ***cannot*** possibly know the locale setting that are configured for any users version of MS Excel, and handling of locale-specific formattings (such as decimal commas rather than points) is specific to an instance of MS Excel itself. If I opened that same file in my copy of MS Excel, then I would see a decimal point... i.e. local settings aren't defined in the file, they're purely in the MS Excel GUI.

If you need to format specific to a users locale, then retrieve the raw data using `getValue()`, and use PHP's [Intl NumberFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) to localise the format.

Comment: Are there a way to detect if the row is General?
If so I can check if it is numeric and then convert it with Intl NumberFormatter. The ->getDataType return 's' for both General and Text...

Comment: "General" is a format mask setting: `$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode()`

Comment: I did some test, and I can't just convert it to my locale. Because the user can type on excel 1,50 or 1.50. If I just convert, everything will be 1,50 on my locale...